# Ruby on rails: how to exclude certain path from rack middleware authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, basic-authentication

I am trying to use rack middleware authentication. I want to exclude certain path from the authentication. 
Is it possible to exclude some specific path?

This will authenticate all the routes starts with home.

```
def call(env)
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  if request.path =~ /^\/home/
    super
  else
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

I want that the path "home/users/" should be excluded from the authentication. All other path starting from "home/" should be authenticate.
Any lead please, thanks.

Comment: What you want to do here? authenticate all other paths than "home/users/" or authenticate path with "/^\/home/" and exclude "home/users/"?

Comment: If you add the `return @app.call(env) if request.path.eql?('home/users/')` line before the if condition, the problem may be resolved.

Comment: @KrupaSuthar Thanks, I am looking for that only, but may you give any lead how to exclude the paths containing "home/users".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude only "home/users/" path then you middleware should have following structure,

```
def call(env)
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  return @app.call(env) if request.path == "home/users/"
  # your middleware logic of authentication here.
end
```

For more information of rack, you can refer [this](https://blog.solutelabs.com/rack-an-interface-b-w-ruby-based-application-and-web-server-cb9d6ee757d1).

Comment: Thanks @krupa suthar

Comment: Let me know if need any further help.